# Как запустить клиент и подключиться к серверу в AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет, android-asynctask

Запускаю на компьютере через командную строку сервер с портом 6666. Подскажите, как я могу к нему подключиться, нажав на кнопку в эмуляторе? У меня появляется в логах "connecting...", а затем ошибка: `W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. При этом когда запускаю сервер и клиент просто отдельными файлами, то все работает, неважно командной строкой или в android studio.
Вот MainActivity:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button but;
    MyTask mt;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        but.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mt = new MyTask();
        mt.execute();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int port = 6666;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int serverPort = 6666; 
            String address = "127.0.0.1"; 

            try {
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
                System.out.println("Connecting...");
                Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);
                System.out.println("Connected");

            } catch (Exception x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: какой адрес вы указываете при подключении на клиенте?

Comment: Попробуйте `String address = "10.0.2.2";`